# Multi-Layered ul/li Menu Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, accordion

I'm having an issue with doing a multi-layered menu.

```
<style type="text/css">
body,input{font-family:Calibri,Arial}
#canopy{list-style:none;padding:0 0 0 0;width:170px}
#canopy li{display:block;background-color:#DBDBDB;font weight:bold;margin:1px;cursor:pointer;padding:5 5 5 7px;list-style:square;}
#canopy ul{list-style:none;padding:0 0 0 0;display:none}
#canopy ul li{font-weight:normal;cursor:auto;background-color:#fff;padding:0 0 0 7px}
#canopy a{text-decoration:none}
#canopy a:hover{text-decoration:underline}

#menu {
position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}

#page {
position: relative;
left: 200px;
top: 0px;
}
</style>

<div id="menu">
<ul id="canopy">

 <li>Continental View</li>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">United States</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Alaska</a></li>
</ul>
<li>Regional View</li>
<ul>
    <li>Northeast</li>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="one" href="#" onclick="changeIt('image1');">2m Temperature</a></li>
        <li><a id="two" href="#" onclick="changeIt('image2');">2m Dew Point</a></li>
        <li><a id="three" href="#" onclick="changeIt('image3');">2m Relative Humidity</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">10m Wind Speed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">10m Wind Gust</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">10m Wet Bulb Temp</a></li>
    </ul>

    </li>
    </ul>

<li>Metro View</li>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Boston</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Burlington</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New York City</a></li>


</ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$("#canopy > li").click(function(){
    if(false==$(this).next().is(':visible')){
        $('#canopy > ul').slideUp(200);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
$('#canopy > ul:eq(0)').show();
</script>
```

This is an accordion drop-down menu and the structure should go:

Regions
 -Northeast
  -2m Temperature

Instead, the Northeast folder won't open up to reveal the rest of the items.

Comment: NE has an extra `</li>` tag, and there's a missing `</ul>` to close out `<ul id="canopy">`.

Comment: We're missing the javascript code that handles opening the list elements and how the list is associated with it.

Comment: </BODY><SCRIPT>$("#canopy > li").click(function(){if(false==$(this).next().is(':visible')){$('#canopy > ul').slideUp(200);}
$(this).next().slideToggle(300);});$('#canopy > ul:eq(0)').show();</SCRIPT>

Comment: @AaronPerry don't dump additional code in a comment, update the question with it, in a readable form (I've done that for you on this one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML is malformed. You have

```
<ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <ul>
        <!-- Elements -->
    </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Which is not nested correctly, the inner `<ul>` should go inside the `<li>`, i.e.

```
<ul>
  <li>Something
      <ul>
          <!-- Elements -->
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You've also got stray `</li>`s, and the enclosing `<ul>` is missing a closing tag.

---

As for the Javascript, I see two problems, both related to the nesting:

1. You're toggling the `next()` element, which means that clicking on a `li` will toggle its next *sibling* (which once HTML is well formed, will be another `li` on the same level or nothing). Instead, you want to toggle a child list, so use something like `children('ul')` instead.
2. You're associating the click event handler to `#canopy > li`, i.e. the `li` elements which are direct children of `#canopy`, but the *Northeast* list is the children of a children. You could use for instance `$("#canopy > li > ul > li").click(/*...*/)` instead,
   to select the second level li

Comment: Hi there. Thank you very much for answering my question! I'm still having issues with the Northeast folder not opening...